# How can I Import Houdini Pyro VDB Cache data to Blender

Tags: export, import, smoke-simulation, fire

I wan't to Import Pyro simulation from houdini to Blender
I tried to import VDB cache from houdini to blender but it was not compatible with blender and blender could not read it 
Is there any way to do that whether it is Python scripting or any way so that i can bring that pyro smulation from houdini to blender ?

Answer (score 3):

Moving a pyro vdb (or any vdb for that matter) from Houdini to Blender 2.9, is fairly straightforward if your pyro sim is set up with a convert vdb and file cache sop.

Here is the end of the Houdini node tree for the pyro vdb shown below:

[image]

The *convert vdb sop* instructs houdini to convert your pyro into a vdb sequence(change it to vdb, as it defaults to *volume*,) it should look like so in the parameters--> [image], and the *file cache* will save it to disk at the output. (be sure to change cache to output to .vdb from .bgeo or you may run into problems on export)

---

Alternatively, (and for a more efficient way)you may  use a *Pyro-Post-Process sop* in place of the convert vdb sop. This will allow to do the conversion to vdb and tell houdini to save  the vdb as 16 bit float instead of 32 bit (default).

[image]

The parameters of the pyro-post-process should look like this:

[image]

---

Inside of Blender, add a [*volume object*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/volumes/introduction.html#introduction) in the scene, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Volume *>Import OpenVBD* and [select your sequence](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/volumes/properties.html#openvdb-file) wherever it was saved to. Blender should now read the vdb sequence exported from houdini without any problems.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! In order to save some space on the graphics card for cycles/eevee you might want to add a *primitive sop* after the *vdb conversion* and set it to *16bit* or just put down a *pyro post process* node which allows to do both steps in one go.

Comment: @p2or indeed! Pyro-post-process is much more efficient!